# When will H2 1.4.x finally release a stable version?

Tags: h2

The last stable release Version 1.3.176 was published at 2014-04-05, when will 1.4.x stable version release?

Answer (score 0):

Ask from their google group

1. [MainGroup](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/h2-database)
2. [News about release timeline](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/h2-database/3CDRKex_EgA)